# Write the proposition in words - $\urcorner\left(\forall x P\left(x\right)\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

Hi here is the problem and my answer attempt.

$\urcorner\left(\forall x P\left(x\right)\right)$

Let P(x) denote, "x is taking a math science course". Domain is the set of all students. Write the proposition in words.

Here is my work breakdown and attempt at writing this.

D = {all students}
For every x $\in$ D then P(x); true.
For every x $\ni$ D then P(x); false. 
Word answer: Not every student x is taking a science course.

How does this breakdown and word answer look?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\urcorner \forall$ is the same as $\exists \urcorner$.

Comment: The problem asks to write the proposition in natural language. What are you doing in the middle with those $x$'s and inequalities? What is the relevance of that to the problem?

Comment: another comment - what does $x = 1$ or $x+1$ mean when $x$ is supposed to be a student?

Comment: @GitGud I was trying to show my work / thought process in arriving at this evaluation by assigning a arbitrary value to x. But I suppose the statement is assumed true given that x has no stated value? Or in other words I could assume all students are taking a science class and then just flip b/c of the $\urcorner\left(\right)$

Comment: @mm-aops I think I was thinking of a starting position to loop through the set of D, but I guess I'm seeing the hard way the two dont relate with the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally, we read
$$\neg\left(\forall xP(x)\right)$$
as: "It is not the case ($\neg$) that all ($\forall$) students ($x$) are taking a math science course ($P(x)$)".

What does it mean? If not all students are taking a math science course, then at least one student is taking another course. In logic, we say that "there exists one student who is not taking a math science course", and we translate it as:
$$\exists x\neg P(x)$$
This is a fundamental relation between the universal ($\forall$) and the existential ($\exists$) quantifiers. In fact, we can write (for any domain and predicate):
$$\forall x P(x)\equiv\neg\exists x\neg P(x)$$
And this means that "if everything is $P$, then nothing exists that is not $P$".

Comment: ....thanks again for helping, this too makes much more sense now. Again much appreciated.

Comment: You're very welcome :)